# Spring Boot Hibernate optimistic lock

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a `Spring Boot (1.5.7.RELEASE)` microservice with `JPA` and `Hibernate (5.2.12.Final)`. I use `@Transactional` annotation to perform operations on a table in `SQL Server`. The problem I have is that the save operation takes too much time, so I want the read operations to not be blocked by it. Note that save is performed by persisting the `JPA` entity.

Currently all read operations do not return results until all concurrent save operations are completed, which means the table becomes locked. I would like instead to achieve an optimistic locking. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with transaction isolation levels http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-transaction-isolation-tutorial or use a cache to avoid reading from database.